# Filtering a datatable primevue

Tags: vuejs3

I have a problem in my DataTable PrimeVue and filters.

Firstly, I have a dynamic columns like this:

```
<Column v-for="col of columns" :key="col.field" :field="col.field" :header="col.header"></Column>
```

Then, one of the columns is call `infoId`. This column return an ID and I have to put a function to convert this data ID to a name like this:

```
<template
#body="slotProps"
v-if="col.field === 'infoId'">
    {{this.getinfoId(slotProps.data.infoId)}}
 </template>
```

This is working fine, but when I want to add a filtering PrimeVue it's not working. If I remove the function, and the column return an ID, the filtering is working fine, but with the function not.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Filtering is not working?  What filtering?  Show the code please.  Explain the issue more if you can.  "not working" isn't a good technical description of a problem.  It's not clear what you mean.  Any errors? Does it filter but does so incorrectly? What is the expected vs actual result?  Have you tried any debugging?  Review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Creating MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Making a better question will more likely lead to a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue. Primevue does filtering only on the original data (:value prop), not on whatever you actually display in columns. You need custom filters for any data transformations (example here: https://primevue.org/filterservice).